# Can Knuth's "Font36" or other dissection fonts be downloaded anywhere or called in TeX?

Tags: fonts

I'm looking for more information on how to make use of Knuth's "Font36", a font in which every character has the same geometric area. I've searched around but can't find out if there's somewhere to download it for personal/research use.

[image]

[image]

The font is described in Fascicle 9b, "A Potpurri of Puzzles": https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/fasc9b.ps.gz, and can be "played with" here: http://erikdemaine.org/fonts/dissect/ but I'm wondering if there's a way to download it or else use it in TeX/LaTeX.

Here are some other useful dissection and puzzle fonts that would be nice to download & use: http://erikdemaine.org/fonts/

Comment: Have you tried to sent a mail to the author of that page?